# Why the second textview didn't go to right as expected, but the first one did?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-linearlayout

I have the following XML layout.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="84dp"
    android:layout_height="84dp"
    android:padding="16dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:gravity="bottom|start"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:gravity="top|start"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

On LTR android devices, all things seems well. But the second text view goes to left on an RTL device as attached image.

[textview2 shown from left to right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD3sf.jpg)

And my custom adapter is:

```
class NumbersViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NumbersView> {
```

Invoke the constructor of the ArrayAdapter class, and pass the context and arrayList for the super constructor of the ArrayAdapter class

```
    public NumbersViewAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<NumbersView> arrayList) {


        super(context, 0, arrayList);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        // convertView which is recyclable view
        View currentItemView = convertView;

        // if the recyclable view is null then inflate the custom layout for the same
        if (currentItemView == null) {
            currentItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_row_test, parent, false);
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text1 =  currentItemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.text2 =  currentItemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            holder.image = currentItemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            currentItemView.setTag(holder);
        }

        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) currentItemView.getTag();

        // get the position of the view from the ArrayAdapter
        NumbersView currentNumberPosition = getItem(position);

        // then according to the reference in  the view holder assign the desired image for the same
        ImageView numbersImage = viewHolder.image;
        assert currentNumberPosition != null;
        numbersImage.setImageResource(currentNumberPosition.getNumbersImageId());

        // then according to the reference in  the view holder assign the desired TextView 1 for the same
        TextView textView1 = viewHolder.text1;
        textView1.setText(currentNumberPosition.getNumberInDigit());

        // then according to the reference in  the view holder assign the desired TextView 2 for the same
        TextView textView2 = viewHolder.text2;
        textView2.setText(currentNumberPosition.getNumbersInText());

        // then return the recyclable view
        return currentItemView;
    }
}
```

Why this happened?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue on my device. Could you add your recyclerview adapter code?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @BenP.  I've edited my question. It's ListView not RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

That would be because English letters are written LTR
and numbers can be both

you can try with RTL written languages like Arabic
if you try to add
tools:text="ثلاثه"
you will get it RTL